# Trouble understanding reference definitions

Tags: c++, reference, definitions

I don't quite understand why the output on this is 10 10 if ri is a reference to i...

```
int i, &ri = i;
i = 5; 
ri = 10;
std::cout << i << " " << ri << std::endl;
```

Could someone clear this up for me?

Similarly,

```
int i = 0, &r1 = i;
double d = 1, &r2 = d;

r2 = r1;
std::cout << r2;  // output 0
i = r2;
std::cout << i;  // output 0
r1 = d;
std::cout << r1; // output 0
```

If i = r2 and r2 is a refrence to d when d = 1, why isn't the ouput 1?  Also, when r1 = d, why isn't the output 1 as well?

Comment: You can't reassign references.

Comment: But if r2 = d then why isn't the output on r2 = r1, 1?

Comment: In the first snippet, `ri` is an alias for `i`.

Comment: @Tyler, after assignment r2=r1, while r1 = i, 0, r2 is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference is just like addressing the original item. Like  *(& some_variable)

In your code therefore the line

```
r2 = r1;
```

sets the value of `d` to the value of `i` which is `0`.

from then on all values are `0`

if you replace the names `r1` with `ref_i` and `r2` to `ref_d` it will make sense.

Try it here:

http://ideone.com/SHxQLN

```
int i = 0, &ref_i = i;
double d = 1, &ref_d = d;

ref_d = ref_i;       // <<-------------------- Put value of i into d
std::cout << ref_d; 

i = ref_d;
std::cout << i;

ref_i = d;
std::cout << ref_i;
```

Comment: Thank you! That site is pretty useful!

Comment: The really important thing to take away from here is that code that has good naming conventions will make your algorithms much easier to write, understand, debug and thus lowers the cost of maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Think of reference as an alias (an alternative name) for an object. Whatever you do with a reference you do with the object it refers to. Here:

```
int i, &ri = i;
```

you say that ri is another name for i. Thus, here:

```
i = 5;
```

you set i = 5, and here

```
ri = 10;
```

you set i = 10.